# Jarsigner doesn't sign plugin dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, jar-signing

In a maven repository I have an eclipse plugin, which I need in order to create a feature. The local dependency `test.branding.plugin` is signed, but the downloaded from nexus `test.plugin.nexus` isn't.

This is how I have defined the dependency in my parent pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the rest of the pom.xml file.

```
<modules>
    <module>../test.feature</module>
    <module>../test.branding.plugin</module>
    <module>../test.p2</module>
</modules>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resolver>p2</resolver>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>macosx</os>
                        <ws>cocoa</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
                <allowConflictingDependencies>true</allowConflictingDependencies>
                <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>../test.parent/cert.jks</keystore>
                <storepass>storepass</storepass>
                <alias>alias</alias>
                <keypass>keypass</keypass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-sigalg</argument>
                    <argument>MD5withRSA</argument>
                    <argument>-digestalg</argument>
                    <argument>SHA1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <format>yyyyMMdd-HHmm</format>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A  couple of questions that can help understand what is going on, what is `test.plugin.nexus` , is it a separate dependency? Also how do you deploy the artifacts in nexus, is it via the release plugin?

Comment: test.plugin.nexus is an eclipse plugin, which is uploaded in nexus. maven-deploy-plugin deploys in nexus.

Comment: Why don't you sign `test.plugin.nexus` when you build it?

Comment: That's the best solution, but I don't have access to the build process of that artifact.

Comment: So you are signing an artifact you haven't built yourself? Could you post your certificate so that I can explicitly distrust it?

Comment: @oberlies: The plugin is from trusted source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a workaround. If you put jarsigner into your normal lifecycle, it will only sign the artifacts of your modules.

You can, however put the jarsigner plugin into your p2-module instead, retroactivly signing all your jars before zipping the p2 repository.

For this to work, you have to enter the call of `jarsigner:sign` between `tycho-p2-repository-plugin:assemble-repository` and `tycho-p2-repository-plugin:archive-repository`, i.e. after the blown out p2 is created, but before it is zipped. Since both goals are run in the same phase, you need a trick:

You need to move `tycho-p2-repository-plugin:assemble-repository` into an earlier phase (`prepare-package`).

Have a look at this example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-assemble-repository</id>
        <!-- execute the assemble step in prepare-package -->
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <keystore>../test.parent/cert.jks</keystore>
      <storepass>storepass</storepass>
      <alias>alias</alias>
      <keypass>keypass</keypass>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-sigalg</argument>
        <argument>MD5withRSA</argument>
        <argument>-digestalg</argument>
        <argument>SHA1</argument>
      </arguments>
      <archiveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/repository</archiveDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>features/*.jar</include>
        <!-- potentially only sign specific plugins -->
        <include>plugins/*.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>sign</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>sign</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Result is a zip file containing all jars.

However, there is one small caveat:

The size of the artifacts increase due to signing, but the relevant size properties in artifacts.jar are not adjusted. This currently has no effect (it is only used to generate download progress bars in special situations), but it **could** lead to problems using some future p2 implementation.

**Update**

Seems the problem with the wrong checksum is known (see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347041).

Try to use `eclipse-maven-signing-plugin` to do all the necessary unpacking and adapting:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- <groupId>org.eclipse.dash.maven</groupId> -->
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipse-signing-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>fixMD5Sums</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>fixCheckSums</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.zip</inputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This seems somewhat outdated, but could still work. Eclipse-maven-signing-plugin seems also to be able to do the whole signing process itself, but this would need further investigation.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this artifact test.plugin contains md5 checksum in artifacts.xml. When I sign the p2 repository after creating it, I get an error executing merge p2-repository, that the md5 checksum of test.plugin.nexus doesn't match. So I need a way either to sign the dependency before the creation of the p2 repository or somehow to update the metadata after that. The third option is to disable the generation of md5 checksum in artifacts.xml..

Comment: The part that you use p2-extras-plugin is an important information. Where do you include it? separate step? separate module?

Comment: p2-extras-plugin is not called from the same project. I call it later when I want to merge the build with the p2 repository. Why is that important?

Comment: Because up to this point, I thought he would now even create the repository.

Comment: I think I found a solution, updating answer.

Comment: The bounty expires soon. I don't think there will be other effort for a solution, so I'll give you the bounty. I'll test your update and let you know if it works, but it looks it's the right solution! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Not necessary, was an interesting problem. Take a look at `eclipse-signing-maven-plugin`, this could be a solution. Or else: unpack manually using antrun -> unzip -> xsl -> zip